# How to enforce stack ordering in ggplot geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to enforce the stack order when using `geom_area()`? I cannot figure out why `geom_area(position = "stack")` produces this strange fluctuation in stack order around 1605.

There are no missing values in the data frame.

```r
library(ggplot2)

counts <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mdlincoln/d5e1bf64a897ecb84fd6/raw/34c6d484e699e0c4676bb7b765b1b5d4022054af/counts.csv")

ggplot(counts, aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + geom_area()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to order your data. In your data, the first value found for each year is 'Flemish' until 1605, and from 1606 the first value is 'Dutch'. So, if we do this:

```
ggplot(counts[order(counts$nationality),], 
       aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + geom_area()
```

It results in

[image]

Further illustration if we use random ordering:

```
set.seed(123)
ggplot(counts[sample(nrow(counts)),], 
       aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of ggplot2 were you using? I could not reproduce this in 2.2.0. The ordering was automatic in this version. Unfortunately, this also means that we cannot switch which group is on top as easily (I have not figured out how yet).

Answer (score 4):

As [randy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4200548/randy) said, ggplot2 2.2.0 does automatic ordering.  If you want to change the order, just reorder the factors used for fill.  If you want to switch which group is on top in the legend but not the plot, you can use scale_fill_manual() with the limits option.

(Code to generate ggplot colors from [John Colby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412342/john-colby))

```
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}
cols <- gg_color_hue(2)
```

Default ordering in legend

```
ggplot(counts, 
   aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) +
geom_area()+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("Dutch" = cols[1],"Flemish"=cols[2]),
   limits=c("Dutch","Flemish"))
```

Reversed ordering in legend

```
ggplot(counts, 
   aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + 
geom_area()+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("Dutch" = cols[1],"Flemish"=cols[2]),
   limits=c("Flemish","Dutch"))
```

Reversed ordering in plot and legend

```
counts$nationality <- factor(counts$nationality, rev(levels(counts$nationality)))
ggplot(counts, 
   aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + 
geom_area()+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("Dutch" = cols[1],"Flemish"=cols[2]),
   limits=c("Flemish","Dutch"))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it for you

```
ggplot(counts[order(counts$nationality),], 
aes(x = year, y = artists_strict, fill = factor(nationality))) + geom_area()
```

hope this helps